# Is there a way to stop VS2015 Typescript compilation on build?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm running a Asp.Net Core RC2, project.json project and have setup gulp to watch and compile my typescript to a different location. But Visual Studio 2015 is also compiling the typescript each time I compile, giving me duplicates of each js file. How do I stop VS from compiling my typescript files.

I have disabled compile on save in my `tsconfig.json`, but there seams to be no options for disabled it on build.

`{
    "compileOnSave": false
}`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In RC2, you can disable it by adding **TypeScriptCompileBlocked** to the .xproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This also works for the new msbuild .csproj based tooling.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, add this to you **.xproj** file

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```